# Android - find image link API

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

**Hey !**

I have an Android app where the user can search on a specific subject, let's take the word "Cats" for example. When the user submits the search I want to find an image similar or on the subjects the searched for. **A search engine for images more or less. I want something "easy" to deal with**, so I thought about integrating the Google Search API into my app. Let the user search Google, and take the first image that comes up.

However, I haven't found any example and I just need a push in the right direction. If you could give me an example API for my needs, that'd be great.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I understand that. I made research, however couldn't find anything that could potentially be solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apparently the Google Search API never was fully deprecated it's still up and running. It provides JSON data and is easily parsed with Android.**

If anyone else needs an image API here's a test search: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=searchquery&rsz=8&start=1&imgsz=small|medium

And the JSON reference: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide